# Query DTO objects through WCF with linq to sql backend

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, linq, dto

I am working on a project where we need to create complex queries against
a WCF service.

The service uses linq to sql at the backend and projects queries to data transfer objects like  this:

```
    dbContext.GetQueryable()
                  .Where(x => x.Id == formatId)
                    .Select(x => FormatHelper.PopulateMSFormat(x))
                    .ToList();
```

What I want to do is to specify a query on the client side, lets say i want to query all formats having a certain property or a couple of them. 
Something in the style of this:

```
     var assets = client.QueryForAssets().Where(x => (x.name == "Test" || x == "Arne") && x.doe ==  "john");
```

Iam aware that I can't return IQueryable over WCF but that something like that can be done with OData services. The problem is that I have to return the DTO's and OData let me quite easily bind to L2S-datacontext which exposes my data model and not the DTO's.

So is there a good way of serializing a query against the DTO that efficiently will propagate to the l2s layer?

I thought about writing my own query language, but I found out that it would be quite hard to build the correct expression tree as a predicate to l2s as there is no mapping from the DTO to the linq classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `OData` services, you are not bound to return database entities directly. You can simply return any `DTO` in queryable format. Then with the help of LINQ's `Select()` method, you can simply convert any database entity into `DTO` just before serving the query:

```
public class DataModel
{
  public DataModel()
  {
    using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
      Employees = from e in dbContext.Employee
                  select new EmployeeDto
                  {
                    ID = e.EmployeeID,
                    DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID,
                    AddressID = e.AddressID,
                    FirstName = e.FirstName,
                    LastName = e.LastName,
                    StreetNumber = e.Address.StreetNumber,
                    StreetName = e.Address.StreetName
                  };
    }
  }

  /// <summary>Returns the list of employees.</summary>
  public IQueryable<EmployeeDto> Employees { get; private set; }
}
```

You can now easily set this up as a OData service like this:

```
public class EmployeeDataService : DataService<DataModel>
```

For full implementation details, [see this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/135490/Advanced-using-OData-in-NET-WCF-Data-Services) excellent article on the subject. OData services are actually very very powerful once you get the hand of them.

Comment: It sounds like a good solution but I cant get it to work. I Suspect it has something to do with the fact that I use L2S and not EF

Comment: Found at least two problems. I can't use a helper method and since the context is wrapped in using it will be disposed when the collection is queried.

Comment: Using L2S or EF doesn't matter. You can pool the data from any source. Since OData service objects are created 'per-request', having a `using` statement is the right way as the `DataModel` class instance will be created and destroyed along with the request.

Comment: I disagree on the using statement, the dispose method will be called as soon datacontext goes out of scope, which is before Get() gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can return DTO's by using OData services.

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/135490/Advanced-using-OData-in-NET-WCF-Data-Services. Particularly the 'Exposing a transformation of your database' section. You can flatten your entity objects into a DTO and have the client run queries against this DTO model.

Is that something you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have long complicated entities then creating a projection by hand is a nightmare. `Automapper` doesn't work because LINQ cannot use it in conjunction with IQueryable.

This here is the perfect solution : [`Stop using AutoMapper in your Data Access Code`](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code)

It will generate a projection 'magically' for you and enable you to run an oData query based on your DTO (data transfer object) class.

```
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<DatabaseProductDTO> GetDatabaseProductDTO(ODataQueryOptions<DatabaseProductDTO> options)
    {
        // _db.DatabaseProducts is an EF table 
        // DatabaseProductDTO is my DTO object
        var projectedDTOs = _db.DatabaseProducts.Project().To<DatabaseProductDTO>();

        var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
        var results = (IQueryable<DatabaseProductDTO>) options.ApplyTo(projectedDTOs, settings);

        return results.ToArray().AsQueryable();
    }
```

I run this with

```
/odata/DatabaseProductDTO?$filter=FreeShipping eq true
```

Note: this article is from a couple years ago and it's possible that by now `AutoMapper` has functionality like this built in. I just don't have time I check this myself right now. The inspiration for the above referenced article was based on [this article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/02/09/autoprojecting-linq-queries/) by the author of AutoMapper itself - so it's possible some improved version of it is now included. The general concept seems great and this version is working well for me.