# Is it possible to map Linq queries from one Data Model to a query over a different data model?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, odata

I would like to provide an OData interface for my application. The examples that I have seen use EF to map the LINQ queries to SQL queries.

IMHO it this approach pretty much exposes the physical database model to the world (I know EF/NH give some flexibility, but it is limited).

What I would like the be able to do, is the following:

1. Define my Data Contract via some DTOs.
2. Have a OData Service that will let users query over my Data Contract Dtos.
3. Have some translation layer to translate the queries over the DTOs to queries over, let's say, EF model or NH.
4. Execute the translated query.
5. Map the results back to my Data Contracts.

Am I out of my mind or is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query DTO objects through WCF with linq to sql backend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806492/query-dto-objects-through-wcf-with-linq-to-sql-backend)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 models, the "contract" model and the "persisted" model. The persisted model is what Entity Framework is mapped to. The Get method that returns an IQueryable returns a IQueryable which is just something along the lines of:

```
return dbContext.PersistedCustomers.Select(x => new Customer(Name = x.OtherName, ...));
```

At least when using DbContext as opposed to ObjectContext, Where criteria based on the contract model get translated automatically into Where criteria of the PersistedModel to be executed against the database. Hopefully the differences between the two aren't that complex that you need some weird data massaging. I'm sure there's limits to the reversal it does.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to create a ViewModel that will represent your Model and then use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map between them. You can use like this:

```
   var address = _Context.Addresses.Where(p => p.AddressID == addressID).Single();
   AddressVM result = Mapper.Map<AddressVM>(address);
```